# Exception when calling Autodesk forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am using web application with forge viewer.When uploading 1GB file in forge viewer its throwing exception.

This error is getting from below line of coding.

```
 newObject = Await objectsApi.UploadObjectAsync(bucketKey, m_strFileName,
                     Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.BaseStream.Length), fileStream.BaseStream,
                       "application/octet-stream")
```

Exception message : Error calling UploadObject

at Autodesk.Forge.ObjectsApi.d__57.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Autodesk.Forge.ObjectsApi.d__56.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at CommonGUI.mtequipments.VB$StateMachine_2279_btn_bimfile_Click.MoveNext() in D:\Projects

Could you please help me for this. I need to upload large size files in forge viewer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great possibility that the upload has timeouted.

For large model file, please consider using the resumable endpoint [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/). In C# SDK, it's [uploadchunk](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadchunk).

Here is an example: https://github.com/yiskang/ForgeResumableUploadProgressDemo/blob/master/ForgeResumableUploadProgressDemo/Program.cs